# Drawing a pair of lines to the x-axis and y-axis from a point along a curve

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have some plot like the following:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {Style["x-axis", 12], Style["y-axis", 12]}, ImageSize -> {650, 650}]
```

I'd like to be able to specify a point along the x-axis and draw a line of some color from this point to a point immediately above or below it falling along the given curve, and then draw a line from this point on the curve to a point immediately to the left or right of the point on the curve to a point on the y-axis (wherever either of these two axes are positioned).  Is there a built-in way to do this in Mathematica 9?

The purpose of this is to make it obvious where a point p on the curve falls along the x-axis and y-axis in the plot.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this, `Epilog`?

```
With[{expr = Cos[x], x0 = 5.4}, 
 Plot[expr, {x, -10, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x-axis", 12], Style["y-axis", 12]}, 
  ImageSize -> {650, 650},
  Epilog -> {Lighter@Red, 
    Line[{{x0, 0}, {x0, expr /. x -> x0}, {0, expr /. x -> x0}}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or perhaps with `GridLines`?

```
With[{expr = Cos[x], x0 = 5.4}, 
 Plot[expr, {x, -10, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x-axis", 12], Style["y-axis", 12]}, 
  ImageSize -> {650, 650},
  GridLines -> {{x0}, {expr /. x -> x0}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Lighter@Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]